# How to set height with float?

Tags: css

I need to set `height:100%`. Here is my code:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 10px 0 0 !important;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

#left-side{
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
#right-side{
    border: 1px solid green;
}

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-side">
            lol
        </div>
        <div id="right-side">
            <!-- squares -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: picture]

Where is the problem?

Comment: FLoated elements take only the height of their own content, unless it is also floated, in which case it takes none.

Comment: @JimmyRare `<div id="left-side">lol</div>` should be 100% height.

Comment: Does it *need* to be floated?

Comment: height 100% refers to it's parent. the wrappers parent is body, and the body's parent is html.
So try html, body { height: 100% }

[http://jsfiddle.net/r8E8D/](http://jsfiddle.net/r8E8D/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with percentages, it's relative to it's parent.
Your `#wrapper` has a parent (`body`) with no defined height.

In your css, add:

```
    html, body { height: 100% }
```

And now your `#wrapper` can relate to it's parent. This is because `html` has the browser window as it's parent, the `body html` as it's parent and so on.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8E8D/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the CSS a bit.Check if this is what u need

```
#wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 10px 0 0 !important;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

#left-side{
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

#right-side{
    width:600px;
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: I have the removed the 100% width of wrapper and changed that to static width

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply have equal height columns, the `display: table` properties work very well for this:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 10px 0 0 !important;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
    display: table; /* here */
}

#left-side{
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: table-cell; /* replaces the float */
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 20px 0 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
#right-side{
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table-cell; /* here */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VTCxs/

If your goal is to simply prevent the images in `#right-side` from flowing around `#left-side`, then you'll need to add a margin or padding equal to the width of `#right-side` to `#left-side`.

Answer (score 0):

If the 100% height should mean the full screen, you'll have to set html and body tag to 100%, to be sure that the wrapper is really wrapping the nested containers you'll have to add a float break for the wrapper element.

```
html,body {
 height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 10px 0 0 !important;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#wrapper:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;

}
```

[Here is a small demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/fLtfu/). In moment you'll will always get a scrollbar, bescause your wrapper has a height of 100% plus the padding of 50px top.